# how to put an expandable list inside a ActionBar tab fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview

Hi im a bit noob in android so i hope anyone can help me
`i have an actionBar tab fragment, and i wanted to make a expandable list with data and put it on the fragment, i´ve been searching online but the examples are too complex and dont match my situation i just want a simple expandable list, can anyone help?`

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Any code snippet or your tried logic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should only put ExpandableList inside of your fragment layout for particular layout for actionBar tab fragment. This should be really easy actually...
Can you provide us with some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

this is my class tabActionBarActivity:

```
public class TabActionBarActivity extends Activity {

String contextoId;
String BuId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_action_bar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label1);

    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> tl = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);

   tab.setTabListener(tl);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);


    String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
            tab = actionBar.newTab();
            tab.setText(label2);
            TabListener<Tab2Fragment> tl2 = new TabListener<Tab2Fragment>(this, label2, Tab2Fragment.class);
            tab.setTabListener(tl2);
            actionBar.addTab(tab);


            BuId =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("BUId");
            contextoId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CId");
            Log.i("BUIdTabFrag", BuId);







private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;


        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
                        mActivity = activity;
                        mTag = tag;
                        mClass = clz;
                    }



        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             // Check if the fragment is already initialized
                        if (mFragment == null) {
                            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                        } else {
                            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                            ft.attach(mFragment);
                        }


        }




        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
             if (mFragment != null) {
                                 // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
                                 ft.detach(mFragment);
                             }


        }




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tab_action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and